# Moving an evaluation to a helper in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following evaluation which works great:

In my listings/detail.html.erb view

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.id == @listing.user_id %>
```

I use this several times in my views so I wanted to make this a helper method.

What code can I place in my listings_helper file so I can call something like this in my view instead:

```
<% if isListingOwner? %>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I need to do something like that, I use Cancan. Then you can write stuff like:

```
<% if can?(:update, @listing) %>
  Listing
<% end %>
```

In my view much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Put it to `/app/helpers` folder.

Railscast has intro tutorial on this topic
http://railscasts.com/episodes/64-custom-helper-modules

Answer (score 1):

All good suggestions, but the code you need to add to your listings_helper.rb is

```
def isListingOwner?
  user_signed_in? && current_user.id == @listing.user_id
end
```

Personally, I'd rather put that check in the model:

```
class Listing
  def owned_by?(user)
    user.id == self.user_id
  end
end
```

Then in your view, you would write:

```
<% if @listing.owned_by(current_user) %>
```

You might want to look into a role based authorization plugin if you're doing a lot of this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `belongs_to :user` in your `Listing` model, why don't you simply do

```
if current_user == @listing.user
```

I'm assuming you're using Devise or something that returns nil from current_user when the user is not signed in.